# Animated Wallpaper Development for iPhones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, opengl-es

I an interested in making animated wallpaper apps for the iPhone. This means that, once I click the app to open, it should not open up a view, and it should change the current wallpaper of the iPhone to the an animated wallpaper(which I have designed), while the App is running.

If I close the app, it should bring the iPhone back to the initial wallpaper.

1. How do I go about this ?
2. How can I modify changes to the wallpaper of the iPhone with my app.
3. How  can I place my customized wallpaper in a way that the iPhone operates normally and you can scroll to other apps and stuff while the background wallpaper is animated ?
4. What tools are needed for that animation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create an application that swaps out the background wallpaper.

**This can only be a jail broken app.**

We do not have access to the springboard wallpaper on a normal device with the SDK. So this type of app can only be a jail broken app an a jail broken device and in a jail broken marketplace.

1. The methods you should implement are pretty simple. Would probably be an NSTimer that chooses randomly from an array of image names and sets the background wallpaper.
2. I do not know the immediate functions to use, and they are probably undocumented.
3. Background process app that is always running (like Mail).
4. In the function the timer calls, just make a UIView animation block that shifts the previous image where ever you want and shifts the new one into the view.

What I would suggest is get the functionality you want running in a project. Once that is all done, look into making it a jail broken app and running in the background (this is probably going to be the bulk of the work, and really really hard)

Comment: so without jail breaking, this aint possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not change a users wallpaper programatically, file a feature request with apple like many of us have :)...However you can do it on jailbroken phones...

Comment: How come it is allowed on macs ?

Comment: i would guess mac environment has been around much longer, you also cant really execute code in the background for that long on iOS either without the OS killing you eventually, i dont think you can schedule executable code either...

Comment: Have you seen "Themes for iPhones" on jailbroken phones ?

Comment: you can do it on jaibroken apps...you can do a whole lot of stuff u cant when u jailbreak...should of mentioned that...will update

Comment: i know iOS 5 is under NDA, but i was hoping it would bring this functioanllity however looking through the docs i dont think they have :(

Comment: Hm. Yes, I did not see in the documentation either. I thought there ought to be someone on StackOverflow, who must have had this experience. Oh well... Requiem for my dream !! :|